REFUSED when nslookup-ing domain
I use dnsmasq with "hosts" as a domains table provider. When I am trying to nslookup mole.mishland, it throws that:
nslookup mole.mishland
Server:     192.168.0.34
Address:    192.168.0.34#53

Name:   mole.mishland
Address: 192.168.0.34
** server can't find mole.mishland: REFUSED

But I can succesfully dig, ping this domain and telnet 53 port:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> mole.mishland
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29490
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mole.mishland.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mole.mishland.      0   IN  A   192.168.0.34

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.34#53(192.168.0.34) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 16 10:06:24 MSK 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58




ping mole.mishland
PING mole.mishland (192.168.0.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mole.mishland (192.168.0.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from mole.mishland (192.168.0.34): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from mole.mishland (192.168.0.34): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from mole.mishland (192.168.0.34): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- mole.mishland ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3049ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.046/0.050/0.053/0.002 ms




telnet mole.mishland 53
Trying 192.168.0.34...
Connected to mole.mishland.
Escape character is '^]'.

My dnsmasq config:
# Configuration file for dnsmasq.
#
# Format is one option per line, legal options are the same
# as the long options legal on the command line. See
# "/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --help" or "man 8 dnsmasq" for details.

# Listen on this specific port instead of the standard DNS port
# (53). Setting this to zero completely disables DNS function,
# leaving only DHCP and/or TFTP.
#port=5353

# The following two options make you a better netizen, since they
# tell dnsmasq to filter out queries which the public DNS cannot
# answer, and which load the servers (especially the root servers)
# unnecessarily. If you have a dial-on-demand link they also stop
# these requests from bringing up the link unnecessarily.

# Never forward plain names (without a dot or domain part)
domain-needed
# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv

# Uncomment these to enable DNSSEC validation and caching:
# (Requires dnsmasq to be built with DNSSEC option.)
#conf-file=%%PREFIX%%/share/dnsmasq/trust-anchors.conf
#dnssec

# Replies which are not DNSSEC signed may be legitimate, because the domain
# is unsigned, or may be forgeries. Setting this option tells dnsmasq to
# check that an unsigned reply is OK, by finding a secure proof that a DS 
# record somewhere between the root and the domain does not exist. 
# The cost of setting this is that even queries in unsigned domains will need
# one or more extra DNS queries to verify.
#dnssec-check-unsigned

# Uncomment this to filter useless windows-originated DNS requests
# which can trigger dial-on-demand links needlessly.
# Note that (amongst other things) this blocks all SRV requests,
# so don't use it if you use eg Kerberos, SIP, XMMP or Google-talk.
# This option only affects forwarding, SRV records originating for
# dnsmasq (via srv-host= lines) are not suppressed by it.
#filterwin2k

# Change this line if you want dns to get its upstream servers from
# somewhere other that /etc/resolv.conf
#resolv-file=

# By  default,  dnsmasq  will  send queries to any of the upstream
# servers it knows about and tries to favour servers to are  known
# to  be  up.  Uncommenting this forces dnsmasq to try each query
# with  each  server  strictly  in  the  order  they   appear   in
# /etc/resolv.conf
#strict-order

# If you don't want dnsmasq to read /etc/resolv.conf or any other
# file, getting its servers from this file instead (see below), then
# uncomment this.
no-resolv

# If you don't want dnsmasq to poll /etc/resolv.conf or other resolv
# files for changes and re-read them then uncomment this.
#no-poll

# Add other name servers here, with domain specs if they are for
# non-public domains.
#server=8.8.8.8
#server=8.8.4.4

# Example of routing PTR queries to nameservers: this will send all
# address->name queries for 192.168.3/24 to nameserver 10.1.2.3
#server=/3.168.192.in-addr.arpa/10.1.2.3

# Add local-only domains here, queries in these domains are answered
# from /etc/hosts or DHCP only.
#local=/localnet/

# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in double-click.net to a local
# web-server.
#address=/mole.mishland/192.168.0.34

# --address (and --server) work with IPv6 addresses too.
#address=/www.thekelleys.org.uk/fe80::20d:60ff:fe36:f83

# Add the IPs of all queries to yahoo.com, google.com, and their
# subdomains to the vpn and search ipsets:
#ipset=/yahoo.com/google.com/vpn,search

# Add the IPs of all queries to yahoo.com, google.com, and their
# subdomains to netfilters sets, which is equivalent to
# 'nft add element ip test vpn { ... }; nft add element ip test search { ... }'
#nftset=/yahoo.com/google.com/ip#test#vpn,ip#test#search

# Use netfilters sets for both IPv4 and IPv6:
# This adds all addresses in *.yahoo.com to vpn4 and vpn6 for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
#nftset=/yahoo.com/4#ip#test#vpn4
#nftset=/yahoo.com/6#ip#test#vpn6

# You can control how dnsmasq talks to a server: this forces
# queries to 10.1.2.3 to be routed via eth1
# server=10.1.2.3@eth1

# and this sets the source (ie local) address used to talk to
# 10.1.2.3 to 192.168.1.1 port 55 (there must be an interface with that
# IP on the machine, obviously).
# server=10.1.2.3@192.168.1.1#55

# If you want dnsmasq to change uid and gid to something other
# than the default, edit the following lines.
#user=
#group=

# If you want dnsmasq to listen for DHCP and DNS requests only on
# specified interfaces (and the loopback) give the name of the
# interface (eg eth0) here.
# Repeat the line for more than one interface.
interface=enp5s0
# Or you can specify which interface _not_ to listen on
#except-interface=
# Or which to listen on by address (remember to include 127.0.0.1 if
# you use this.)
listen-address=192.168.0.34, 127.0.0.1
# If you want dnsmasq to provide only DNS service on an interface,
# configure it as shown above, and then use the following line to
# disable DHCP and TFTP on it.
#no-dhcp-interface=

# On systems which support it, dnsmasq binds the wildcard address,
# even when it is listening on only some interfaces. It then discards
# requests that it shouldn't reply to. This has the advantage of
# working even when interfaces come and go and change address. If you
# want dnsmasq to really bind only the interfaces it is listening on,
# uncomment this option. About the only time you may need this is when
# running another nameserver on the same machine.
bind-interfaces

# If you don't want dnsmasq to read /etc/hosts, uncomment the
# following line.
#no-hosts
# or if you want it to read another file, as well as /etc/hosts, use
# this.
#addn-hosts=/etc/banner_add_hosts

# Set this (and domain: see below) if you want to have a domain
# automatically added to simple names in a hosts-file.
#expand-hosts

# Set the domain for dnsmasq. this is optional, but if it is set, it
# does the following things.
# 1) Allows DHCP hosts to have fully qualified domain names, as long
#     as the domain part matches this setting.
# 2) Sets the "domain" DHCP option thereby potentially setting the
#    domain of all systems configured by DHCP
# 3) Provides the domain part for "expand-hosts"
domain=mishland

# Set a different domain for a particular subnet
#domain=wireless.thekelleys.org.uk,192.168.2.0/24

# Same idea, but range rather then subnet
#domain=reserved.thekelleys.org.uk,192.68.3.100,192.168.3.200

# Uncomment this to enable the integrated DHCP server, you need
# to supply the range of addresses available for lease and optionally
# a lease time. If you have more than one network, you will need to
# repeat this for each network on which you want to supply DHCP
# service.
#dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h

# This is an example of a DHCP range where the netmask is given. This
# is needed for networks we reach the dnsmasq DHCP server via a relay
# agent. If you don't know what a DHCP relay agent is, you probably
# don't need to worry about this.
#dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,255.255.255.0,12h

# This is an example of a DHCP range which sets a tag, so that
# some DHCP options may be set only for this network.
#dhcp-range=set:red,192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150

# Use this DHCP range only when the tag "green" is set.
#dhcp-range=tag:green,192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h

# Specify a subnet which can't be used for dynamic address allocation,
# is available for hosts with matching --dhcp-host lines. Note that
# dhcp-host declarations will be ignored unless there is a dhcp-range
# of some type for the subnet in question.
# In this case the netmask is implied (it comes from the network
# configuration on the machine running dnsmasq) it is possible to give
# an explicit netmask instead.
#dhcp-range=192.168.0.0,static

# Enable DHCPv6. Note that the prefix-length does not need to be specified
# and defaults to 64 if missing/
#dhcp-range=1234::2, 1234::500, 64, 12h

# Do Router Advertisements, BUT NOT DHCP for this subnet.
#dhcp-range=1234::, ra-only 

# Do Router Advertisements, BUT NOT DHCP for this subnet, also try and
# add names to the DNS for the IPv6 address of SLAAC-configured dual-stack 
# hosts. Use the DHCPv4 lease to derive the name, network segment and 
# MAC address and assume that the host will also have an
# IPv6 address calculated using the SLAAC algorithm.
#dhcp-range=1234::, ra-names

# Do Router Advertisements, BUT NOT DHCP for this subnet.
# Set the lifetime to 46 hours. (Note: minimum lifetime is 2 hours.)
#dhcp-range=1234::, ra-only, 48h

# Do DHCP and Router Advertisements for this subnet. Set the A bit in the RA
# so that clients can use SLAAC addresses as well as DHCP ones.
#dhcp-range=1234::2, 1234::500, slaac

# Do Router Advertisements and stateless DHCP for this subnet. Clients will
# not get addresses from DHCP, but they will get other configuration information.
# They will use SLAAC for addresses.
#dhcp-range=1234::, ra-stateless

# Do stateless DHCP, SLAAC, and generate DNS names for SLAAC addresses
# from DHCPv4 leases.
#dhcp-range=1234::, ra-stateless, ra-names

# Do router advertisements for all subnets where we're doing DHCPv6
# Unless overridden by ra-stateless, ra-names, et al, the router 
# advertisements will have the M and O bits set, so that the clients
# get addresses and configuration from DHCPv6, and the A bit reset, so the 
# clients don't use SLAAC addresses.
#enable-ra

# Supply parameters for specified hosts using DHCP. There are lots
# of valid alternatives, so we will give examples of each. Note that
# IP addresses DO NOT have to be in the range given above, they just
# need to be on the same network. The order of the parameters in these
# do not matter, it's permissible to give name, address and MAC in any
# order.

# Always allocate the host with Ethernet address 11:22:33:44:55:66
# The IP address 192.168.0.60
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,192.168.0.60

# Always set the name of the host with hardware address
# 11:22:33:44:55:66 to be "fred"
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,fred

# Always give the host with Ethernet address 11:22:33:44:55:66
# the name fred and IP address 192.168.0.60 and lease time 45 minutes
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,fred,192.168.0.60,45m

# Give a host with Ethernet address 11:22:33:44:55:66 or
# 12:34:56:78:90:12 the IP address 192.168.0.60. Dnsmasq will assume
# that these two Ethernet interfaces will never be in use at the same
# time, and give the IP address to the second, even if it is already
# in use by the first. Useful for laptops with wired and wireless
# addresses.
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,12:34:56:78:90:12,192.168.0.60

# Give the machine which says its name is "bert" IP address
# 192.168.0.70 and an infinite lease
#dhcp-host=bert,192.168.0.70,infinite

# Always give the host with client identifier 01:02:02:04
# the IP address 192.168.0.60
#dhcp-host=id:01:02:02:04,192.168.0.60

# Always give the InfiniBand interface with hardware address
# 80:00:00:48:fe:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:f4:52:14:03:00:28:05:81 the
# ip address 192.168.0.61. The client id is derived from the prefix
# ff:00:00:00:00:00:02:00:00:02:c9:00 and the last 8 pairs of
# hex digits of the hardware address.
#dhcp-host=id:ff:00:00:00:00:00:02:00:00:02:c9:00:f4:52:14:03:00:28:05:81,192.168.0.61

# Always give the host with client identifier "marjorie"
# the IP address 192.168.0.60
#dhcp-host=id:marjorie,192.168.0.60

# Enable the address given for "judge" in /etc/hosts
# to be given to a machine presenting the name "judge" when
# it asks for a DHCP lease.
#dhcp-host=judge

# Never offer DHCP service to a machine whose Ethernet
# address is 11:22:33:44:55:66
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,ignore

# Ignore any client-id presented by the machine with Ethernet
# address 11:22:33:44:55:66. This is useful to prevent a machine
# being treated differently when running under different OS's or
# between PXE boot and OS boot.
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,id:*

# Send extra options which are tagged as "red" to
# the machine with Ethernet address 11:22:33:44:55:66
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,set:red

# Send extra options which are tagged as "red" to
# any machine with Ethernet address starting 11:22:33:
#dhcp-host=11:22:33:*:*:*,set:red

# Give a fixed IPv6 address and name to client with 
# DUID 00:01:00:01:16:d2:83:fc:92:d4:19:e2:d8:b2
# Note the MAC addresses CANNOT be used to identify DHCPv6 clients.
# Note also that the [] around the IPv6 address are obligatory.
#dhcp-host=id:00:01:00:01:16:d2:83:fc:92:d4:19:e2:d8:b2, fred, [1234::5] 

# Ignore any clients which are not specified in dhcp-host lines
# or /etc/ethers. Equivalent to ISC "deny unknown-clients".
# This relies on the special "known" tag which is set when
# a host is matched.
#dhcp-ignore=tag:!known

# Send extra options which are tagged as "red" to any machine whose
# DHCP vendorclass string includes the substring "Linux"
#dhcp-vendorclass=set:red,Linux

# Send extra options which are tagged as "red" to any machine one
# of whose DHCP userclass strings includes the substring "accounts"
#dhcp-userclass=set:red,accounts

# Send extra options which are tagged as "red" to any machine whose
# MAC address matches the pattern.
#dhcp-mac=set:red,00:60:8C:*:*:*

# If this line is uncommented, dnsmasq will read /etc/ethers and act
# on the ethernet-address/IP pairs found there just as if they had
# been given as --dhcp-host options. Useful if you keep
# MAC-address/host mappings there for other purposes.
#read-ethers
# Set the DHCP server to enable DHCPv4 Rapid Commit Option per RFC 4039.
# In this mode it will respond to a DHCPDISCOVER message including a Rapid Commit
# option with a DHCPACK including a Rapid Commit option and fully committed address
# and configuration information. This must only be enabled if either the server is 
# the only server for the subnet, or multiple servers are present and they each
# commit a binding for all clients.
#dhcp-rapid-commit

# Run an executable when a DHCP lease is created or destroyed.
# The arguments sent to the script are "add" or "del",
# then the MAC address, the IP address and finally the hostname
# if there is one.
#dhcp-script=/bin/echo

# Set the cachesize here.
#cache-size=150

# If you want to disable negative caching, uncomment this.
#no-negcache

# Normally responses which come from /etc/hosts and the DHCP lease
# file have Time-To-Live set as zero, which conventionally means
# do not cache further. If you are happy to trade lower load on the
# server for potentially stale date, you can set a time-to-live (in
# seconds) here.
#local-ttl=

# If you want dnsmasq to detect attempts by Verisign to send queries
# to unregistered .com and .net hosts to its sitefinder service and
# have dnsmasq instead return the correct NXDOMAIN response, uncomment
# this line. You can add similar lines to do the same for other
# registries which have implemented wildcard A records.
#bogus-nxdomain=64.94.110.11

# If you want to fix up DNS results from upstream servers, use the
# alias option. This only works for IPv4.
# This alias makes a result of 1.2.3.4 appear as 5.6.7.8
#alias=1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8
# and this maps 1.2.3.x to 5.6.7.x
#alias=1.2.3.0,5.6.7.0,255.255.255.0
# and this maps 192.168.0.10->192.168.0.40 to 10.0.0.10->10.0.0.40
#alias=192.168.0.10-192.168.0.40,10.0.0.0,255.255.255.0

# Change these lines if you want dnsmasq to serve MX records.

# Return an MX record named "maildomain.com" with target
# servermachine.com and preference 50
mx-host=mole.mishland,mole.mishland

# Set the default target for MX records created using the localmx option.
#mx-target=servermachine.com

# Return an MX record pointing to the mx-target for all local
# machines.
#localmx

# Return an MX record pointing to itself for all local machines.
#selfmx

# Change the following lines if you want dnsmasq to serve SRV
# records.  These are useful if you want to serve ldap requests for
# Active Directory and other windows-originated DNS requests.
# See RFC 2782.
# You may add multiple srv-host lines.
# The fields are <name>,<target>,<port>,<priority>,<weight>
# If the domain part if missing from the name (so that is just has the
# service and protocol sections) then the domain given by the domain=
# config option is used. (Note that expand-hosts does not need to be
# set for this to work.)

# A SRV record sending LDAP for the example.com domain to
# ldapserver.example.com port 389
#srv-host=_ldap._tcp.example.com,ldapserver.example.com,389

# A SRV record sending LDAP for the example.com domain to
# ldapserver.example.com port 389 (using domain=)
#domain=example.com
#srv-host=_ldap._tcp,ldapserver.example.com,389

# Two SRV records for LDAP, each with different priorities
#srv-host=_ldap._tcp.example.com,ldapserver.example.com,389,1
#srv-host=_ldap._tcp.example.com,ldapserver.example.com,389,2

# A SRV record indicating that there is no LDAP server for the domain
# example.com
#srv-host=_ldap._tcp.example.com

# The following line shows how to make dnsmasq serve an arbitrary PTR
# record. This is useful for DNS-SD. (Note that the
# domain-name expansion done for SRV records _does_not
# occur for PTR records.)
#ptr-record=_http._tcp.dns-sd-services,"New Employee Page._http._tcp.dns-sd-services"

# Change the following lines to enable dnsmasq to serve TXT records.
# These are used for things like SPF and zeroconf. (Note that the
# domain-name expansion done for SRV records _does_not
# occur for TXT records.)

#Example SPF.
#txt-record=example.com,"v=spf1 a -all"

#Example zeroconf
#txt-record=_http._tcp.example.com,name=value,paper=A4

# Provide an alias for a "local" DNS name. Note that this _only_ works
# for targets which are names from DHCP or /etc/hosts. Give host
# "bert" another name, bertrand
#cname=bertrand,bert

# For debugging purposes, log each DNS query as it passes through
# dnsmasq.
#log-queries

# Log lots of extra information about DHCP transactions.
#log-dhcp

# Include another lot of configuration options.
#conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.more.conf
#conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d

# Include all the files in a directory except those ending in .bak
#conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.bak

# Include all files in a directory which end in .conf
#conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf

# If a DHCP client claims that its name is "wpad", ignore that.
# This fixes a security hole. see CERT Vulnerability VU#598349
#dhcp-name-match=set:wpad-ignore,wpad
#dhcp-ignore-names=tag:wpad-ignore

My "hosts" file:
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Torial-Server
192.168.0.34 mole.mishland

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.0.34 mole.mishland
192.168.0.34 mole.mishland

My resolv.conf file:
nameserver 192.168.0.34
nameserver 8.8.8.8


Likely the AAAA query for the IPv6 address(es) that is being refused. Does dig mole.mishland AAAA also return a REFUSED?

@StéphaneChazelas
Yes. I am getting this:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> mole.mishland AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 389
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; EDE: 14 (Not Ready)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mole.mishland.   IN AAAA
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.34#53(192.168.0.34) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 16 22:48:06 MSK 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48

@StéphaneChazelas, oh, as I see AAAA stands for IPv6 record which is not set up on my device.
